# Exporting Popcorn.js TrackedEvents to jSON

Tags: javascript, json, popcornjs

I'm build a VideoAnnotationEditor with Popcorn.js. Users can click on the video when they want to post a comment(=footnote) and enter text and duration. I'm adding footnotes like this:

```
p = pop.footnote({
start: 0,
end: duration,
text: text,
target: "footnotediv"
});
```

When all footnotes are added I want to store the data to a database. But how can I get all footnotes in a nice format? I tried

```
JSON.stringify(pop.getTrackEvents())
```

but it contains a lot und unnecessary stuff. Is there another way or should I store all footnotes in an own data-structure before adding them to popcorn.

Thx for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Popcorn isn't going to do this for you, since it stores it's "private" data on the same object as plugin-specific, user-specified data. Each one of those track event objects will have a bunch of private stuff (`_natives`, `compose`, `_running`, etc) and sometimes semi-private stuff that can be added by the plugin (e.g. `container`).

If you want to filter these out yourself, you can either blacklist the fields you don't want to save or you can whitelist the fields you do. If you have a lot of different plugins, and you don't always know what fields you're going to need, go with the blacklist. But honestly, having done that a few times, I advise just storying your own data structure outside of Popcorn.

But if all you're doing is footnotes, that's relatively simple, and the whitelist approach *should* work. Like so:

```
var trackEvents = pop.getTrackEvents();
trackEvents = trackEvents.map(function (trackEvent) {
    return {
        start: trackEvent.start,
        end: trackEvent.end,
        text: trackEvent.text
    };
});
saveData(JSON.stringify(trackEvents));
```